# Filter function don't return values

Tags: javascript

I would filter a list of objects using filter in JS

```
let dataid = infosStructured.filter(elm => {
  console.log(elm.identifiant);
  console.log("matching value", elm.identifiant == this.dataService.getcurrentId()); // I get a true value
  elm.identifiant == this.dataService.getcurrentId();
});
console.log(dataid); // empty
```

My `dataid` is empty whereas `elm.identifiant == this.dataService.getcurrentId()` is `true` at a given moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multi line code inside `Array.filter()` you need to explicitly mention `return`. For single line like `infosStructured.filter((elm) => elm)` we do not specify the `return` keyword.

```
let dataid = infosStructured.filter(elm => {
  console.log(elm.identifiant);
  console.log("matching value", elm.identifiant == this.dataService.getcurrentId()); // I get a true value
  elm.identifiant == this.dataService.getcurrentId();
  return elm;
});
console.log(dataid);
```

If you do not need `console.log()` inside filter then you can change that in one liner without `return` keyword as:

```
let dataid = infosStructured.filter((elm) => elm.identifiant == this.dataService.getcurrentId());
console.log(dataid);
```

Comment: You need to return the conditional, not the value, otherwise it's pointless using `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with `functional-programming`. Try below code

```
let f = a => { a == 1 };
f(1); // undefined
let g = a => a == 1;
g(1); // true
let h => a => { return a == 1; };
h(1); // true
```

It's a good idea not to use inlined function to debug higher order function.